# Long running WCF service block others

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I had InstanceContextMode set to PerSession/PerCall through ServiceHost

```
Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>().InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession;
Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>().UseSynchronizationContext = false;
ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
{
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000,
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1000,
    MaxConcurrentInstances = 1000
};
Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);
```

New service instance gets created for each call. However, as I know, WCF services use threads from ThreadPool, those requests will be queued to available threads until it decides to start new one. When there is a service with long running operation, it blocks ( some? ) subsequent requests from being processed.

I even tried to set ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads() and ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() to high value but still no luck.

So, what is good pratice to handle this kind of problem?

**Edit: I tried different combination of PerSession/PerCall with ConcurrencyMode but it did not work. Its only non-blocking when i raise the number or Maximum Worker Process in IIS setting**

***Edit after quite some time : Now I understand that its not recommended to run long-running actions inside WCF service because it uses ThreadPool. Since one blocking request will cause all subsequent requests ( that are automatically queued to some limitted thread amount, until ThreadPool decide that it should spawn more thread ). So i'm leaving it here for people who faces same problem.***

Comment: What is being block request from same client or other client request? And what is your messaging pattern? Request/Reply, Duplex etc?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its blocked for the same client only

Comment: I used the default messaging pattern ( which is Request/Reply , I believe ? )

Comment: Are you sure this is a WCF issue? Perhaps the requests are using a database and you're facing database locking issues?

Comment: The request blocking other requests is an restful call to an external service. Thats why its taking so long @zmbq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` as InstanceContextMode it instructs the service application to create a new service object when a new communication session is established between a client and the service application. **Subsequent calls in the same session are handled by the same object**.

The main reason why succeeding request from same client got block because it has something to do with ConcurrencyMode which is by default Single. What does it mean? It means that no request/calls can interrupt ongoing process of the service because it use only single thread to process the first request other succeeding request got block or queued waiting for service to be available and it will get timeout eventually if the first process is not yet finish. In addition service doesn't allow re-entrant.

If you want to understand if fully see links below because it interact to each other.

[InstanceMode and Concurrency Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, the code i pasted is after i've played with those parameters. It is still blocking with PerCall setting.  I'll edit the question.
Also, The request blocking other requests is an restful call to an external service, thats why its taking so long. Do you have other idea on what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: Can you add those details in your question architecturally. You mean client -> service -> call other service? There are many reasons why it's blocking the request.

Comment: Yes, one of the services from our backend calling to an external service ( like google.com ) and waitting for respond. This long operation blocks other services from being processed

Comment: That's not good because it usually ends up hugging of resources in your service. Does your client need to wait for external service result back to service to client? If not, implement fire and forget in your service so that your client won't block

Comment: Yeah, but thats the legacy code and architecture that i'm having to deal with so i'm afraid that logic cant be altered. I'm just wondering if the queueing in same thread like that should be expected for that kind of configuration or i messed up somewhere...

Comment: If you can't alter the logic or codebase I'm afraid to say but I can't figure out how to solve it in configuration alone :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135056/discussion-between-jtabuloc-and-qkhanhpro).